# Validating decimals in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have symfony2 entity mapped to a table using Doctrine. One of the properties is:

```
/**
 * @var decimal $price
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="decimal", nullable=false)
 */
private $price;
```

What `Assert` would satisfy my requirement that `$price` should be a valid decimal?

If I stay things as-is then passing string `foo` as a decimal value will lead to validation error, while passing string `NaN` passes validation, because the string `NaN` is mapped as `float(NaN)` thus treated as a valid decimal value.

Any workarounds?

Symfony dev team assures it is not an issue: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3161

Well, if it is not - then there is probably a solution to validate it. Any ideas?

Comment: And what if someone needs to allow 'NaN' in validation? Just write your own transformer 'non_nan_decimal' ;)

Comment: @meze: omg )) How much steps I need to do to just get the base example from how-to worked? ;-)

Comment: you say 'NaN' is valid value for decimal, and then want it to be converted to 0 because you want so ;)

Comment: @meze: I say it is valid according to validator. For me (and database) - it is not valid value

Comment: i don't see any issues with doctrine orm, it sets empty value for the price field. Also , can't you normalize the price in the setter?

Comment: @meze: yes, the issue is not with doctrine, and I figured it out just today (and posted in that github issue). No, I cannot - the data is transformed in form before the data is passed to the object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From looking at the Symfony documentation, there isn't a built in validator for decimals. You could use a callback validator, or better still you could create your own custom validator like this article [describes here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html).

As for the actual validation, I'd use a combination of `is_numeric` and `is_float` to check. There are methods using regex, but in my opinion if the value satisfies either the `is_numeric` or `is_float` check then you can safely assume it is a valid decimal (or a whole number).

EDIT:

Maybe the best solution would be to validate the decimal as a string. Something like...

```
$stringDecimal = strval($decimalValue);
return (preg_match(/[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/, $stringDecimal) !== 0);
```

Whilst this isn't perfect (you could easily pass '1.15adowadjaow' and it would validate), it serves the basis of what you're after. Combining the above regex with something that searches for anything other than 0-9, fullstop or comma (depending if you want to cater for European decimal formatting).

Comment: `float(NaN)` passes both `is_float` and `is_numeric`

Comment: how about first casting it to a string and checking that the value doesn't equal 'NaN'?

Comment: @zerkms you're right, casting would be more of a sanitization process than validation, a more suitable approach may be to call strval() and then validate the string using regex, i'll update my answer

Comment: It's so weird :-S Wondered that nothing built-in already presents in SF2 :-S

Comment: @zerkms I agree, was surprised that there wasn't something out the box... think I'll report it as an issue on github

Comment: I already did - https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3161 and no one cares :-(

Answer (score 2):

you could try a [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) that checks just for that string.

Comment: Yes, I know about that possibility, but it is just disgusting that they provide a type without possibility to check if it is valid

Comment: "that checks just for that string." -- and this is actually terrible solution. I couldn't have known about any *magic string*. I want to check if data is valid, not to check if data *is invalid*.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using form type for record

```
        ->add(
            'amount',
            'text', change text to number and it will be validated 
            [
                'required' => true
            ]
        )
```

Or you can use range assert

- @Assert\Range(min=0)

it will validate that it should be number

Comment: `float(NaN)` is a number isn't it? Plus `min=0` has different semantics.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `@Assert\Type(type="Numeric")`. Tested in symfony 3.4 but I think it will works with previous versions as well. E.g.

```
 /**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cost", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=4)
 * @Assert\Type(type="Numeric")
 */
private $cost;
```

Thanks!