# Symfony form validation of decimal field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to use the Assert validation rule with decimal and it fails with error.

Here is my form

```
    $builder->add('cinp_number', 'number', array(
        'required' => false,
    ));
```

Here is my Entity

```
 /**
 * @Assert\Type(type="decimal")
 * @var decimal
 */
private $cinp_number;
```

This is the error when submiting form with string value as input:

```
Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed
```

LOG Message:

```
request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed" at C:\wamp\www\top_service\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\DataTransformer\NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer.php line 174 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\ContextErrorException(code: 0): Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed at C:\\wamp\\www\\top_service\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Form\\Extension\\Core\\DataTransformer\\NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer.php:174)"} []
```

Symfony Version: 3.2.13

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validating decimals in symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8979689/validating-decimals-in-symfony-2)

Answer (score 3):

To check that some value in form is decimal one can use following validators:

**Range** in case min/max values are defined http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html

```
/**
 * @Assert\Range(min=0, max=100500)
 */
 private $cinp_number;
```

**Regex** if it's any number, here you can also define allowed format http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex("/^\d+(\.\d+)?/")
 */
 private $cinp_number;
```

**IsTrue** and check everyting manually in a custom method http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/IsTrue.html

```
/**
 * @Assert\IsTrue()
 */
public function isCinpNumberValid()
{
    return $this->cinp_number == (float) $this->cinp_number;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but why won't work TypeAsserts https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html

Answer (score 2):

The `Type` constraint bases on `is_<type>()` or `ctype_<type>()` php functions. There is no `decimal` type in php definition.

Check out the [list of supported types](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Type.html#reference-constraint-type-type) in Symfony Documentation or the list of [Variable handling Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.var.php) / [Ctype Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.ctype.php) in PHP REF.

In your case try `numeric`.

Comment: i tried with `numeric` but i got always the same error when typing string iside the input
`Warning: NumberFormatter::parse(): Number parsing failed`

Comment: This warning may occur before the validation. Please, attach more detailed warning message.

Comment: Show also how you submit the form (values).

Comment: I'm using EasyadminBundle, it handle form submit