# Trouble defining numbers in Entities in API Platform

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

For some reason, API Platform ignores number types and forces strings when defining entities.
The API is configured for JSON API.

Here is an abbreviated example:

```
/**
  * @ApiProperty(
  *     attributes={
  *         "swagger_context"={
  *             "type"="decimal",
  *             "example"="15.00",
  *             "description"="..."
  * }})
  * @Assert\Type("numeric")  
  * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=2, nullable=false, length=6, options={"default":0})
  * @var double
  */
 public $flatFee = 0;
```

Yet when I try to post data as a number, I get a type error expecting a string.

```
{
"data": {
    "type": "my-entity",
    "id": "4",
    "attributes": {
        .....
        "flatFee": 15,   <-- Succeeds only when "15"
```

> **The type of the "flatFee" attribute must be "string", "integer" given.**

Comment: You can try asserting multiple inputs, as ORM will take care of type conversion, try `@Assert\Type(type={"numeric","int","double","float"}) ` etc. as per your inputs. I'm pretty sure your assertion is getting false, checkout [Validation of decimal field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45895022/symfony-form-validation-of-decimal-field)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem doesn't come from Api-Platform, but from a misunderstanding of the decimal type.

With Doctrine, [Decimal type](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.10/reference/types.html#decimal-types) is a PHP string, not a double, that is converted to a decimal in database.

> Values retrieved from the database are always converted to PHP's string type or null if no data is present.

You should consider using [Symfony maker bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) when you create your entities.
As example, when I create a Test entity with a foo decimal property, the generated code will be:

```
$ symfony console make:entity Test
```

*I entered foo for the property name, decimal for the type and 5 then 2 for the numbers*

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TestRepository")
 */
class Test
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
     */
    private $foo;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getFoo(): ?string
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }

    public function setFoo(string $foo): self
    {
        $this->foo = $foo;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, foo is a decimal, but the getter and the setter shall return and accept string values.

So, your swagger context shall be:

```php
/**
  * @ApiProperty(
  *     attributes={
  *         "swagger_context"={
  *             "type"="string",
  *             "example"="15.00",
  *             "description"="A string representing a 6.2 decimal"
  * }})
  * @Assert\Type("numeric")  
  * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=2, nullable=false, length=6, options={"default":0})
  * @var string
  */
 public $flatFee = 0;
```

Comment: This is not the case for me. I have an entity with `$geonameId` `@ORM\Column(type="integer")`, `@var int $geonameId`,  `function getGeonameId(): int` and `function setGeonameId(int $geonameId): self` and despite all these efforts I still get "The type of the `geonameId` attribute for class must be one of `string`"