# Validate precision and scale of decimal field using regex

Tags: php, mysql, regex, symfony, doctrine

A field in my doctrine entity is of type `decimal` having `precision=5` and `scale=2`.

Before storing this entity I need to assert that the given values match the allowed conditions. Since `length` alone cannot handle these conditions:

- lte 3 digits before the decimal
- lte 2 digits after the decimal

I thought of using regex here: `^\d{0,3}(\,\d{0,2})`

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=2)
 * @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^\d{0,3}(\,\d{0,2})/")
 */
private $rate;
```

However, this regex does not seem to work properly as it fails when submitting one of these values:

- `1999,00` (fail is correct)
- `999,00` (should not fail on this one)

---

other cases like `999.005` will not occure as larger values after the decimal are rounded up (`999.01`) which, I assume, is a feature of the decimal field. So this regex may only validate larger values before the decimal.

---

What is wrong about the regex?
Also tried with trailing `?` and `$` without success. (with `?` it is vice versa and fails never)

---

### Solution

Regex `/^[0-9]{0,3}+([,][0-9]{0,2})$/` with `preg_match` in a **custom validator**.

Comment: To be clear 999.00 will not fail but 999.005 will also not fail but will truncate with a warning and you want to reject instead?

Comment: `999` is being transformed to `999.00`. It fails with this regex condition, although it should not. Larger values after the decimal are getting rounded, which I assume is a feature of the decimal field itself. However larger values before the decimal (> 3 digits) fail.

Comment: You can't run a regex on a float value, you can only run it against a string.

Comment: Interesting point. Maybe this cannot be solved through the builtin validator. I'll try a custom validator which works with a string and get back with the result.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew you were right, using the builtin validator (by feeding it with a float value) does not work, although using a custom validator and working with a string value instead works (with that same regex).

Comment: Also you can use a `NumberType` in your `FormType` and define a scale (doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/number.html#scale)). It is advisable to do this, in your case, rather than a regex. Otherwise you must inspire you with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8980206/14632769).

Comment: Yes, I am using a `PercentType`-Field and scale is working, but if the length of numbers on the integral part exceeds, I get an SQL-Error. Thats why I came to this approach and use a custom validator now. Would you suggest another approach?

Comment: Anchor both ends -- ^ at start, $ at end.